# After expressvpn uninstall: no connection to working DNS service anymore after uninstall

Tags: ubuntu, dns, vpn, resolv.conf

During a travel through China I have been using expressVPN with Ubuntu 16.04 After uninstalling it, I could not use internet connections anymore. My /etc/resolv.conf looks like this

```
# Generated by expressvpn
search expressvpn
nameserver 10.19.0.1
```

and I made sure to have a working internet connection as described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/790745/connected-to-wifi-but-no-internet/790770

ssh and scp do work. http, mail protocols don't.

How can I remove expressvpn configurations? I am not able to gain write access to /etc/resolv.conf even with root priviledges. Thank you for your help.

**Edit: The immutable bit was set.**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same after an ExpressVPN uninstall. A most unfortunate experience, and clearly negligent behaviour on their part.

This is what you probably need to do.

Remove the immutable bit on the resolv.conf file as follows:

```
sudo chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then remove all three lines of ExpressVPN, and replace the DNS server either by your own ISP / router IP address, or use a free public third-party DNS server such as Google (8.8.8.8) or OpenNIC.

```
vim /etc/resolv.conf
```

What you do after this is less clear, and depends on your overall configuration. I believe the best source is https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Resolv.conf . They warn you about a number of progams that have a habit of changing resolv.conf, and that you want to protect against. You can either set the immutable bit again to protect against that, or at least add dns=none in the file /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

In my case everything was instantly resolved, and I had internet access again. Perhaps you have already solved it yourself by now, but for (some) others this may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I had to do the following also:

```
# apt remove expressvpn
# apt-get purge expressvpn
# rm -rf /var/lib/expressvpn
# dpkg-reconfigure resolveconf
# reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue and fixed it by running

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf`

and reboot

> source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/784994/resolv-conf-did-not-reset-after-vpn-disconnection